# Typescript Sqlite3 get all promise resolve list

Tags: typescript, database, sqlite, promise

Im curently developing a small kanban app for my own purpose and the backend is based on typescript (im a newbie in TS tbh) and a simple sqlite3 database. So currently i try to fetch data from a database and i have many problems with these promise return.

One table looks like that

```
CREATE TABLE "board" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "position"  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

And my Query is just:

```
SELECT name FROM board ORDER BY position
```

So now I give that string into my async function which returns a promise and i try to get a list out of the function of the titles of the board - looks like that:

```
import { Database } from "sqlite3";





function dbQuery() {
const db = new Database('./data.sqlite3');


return new Promise( resolve => db.serialize(() => {
    var result = [];
    db.all("SELECT name FROM board ORDER BY position", (err, rows) => {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
            //console.log(row['name']);
            result.push(row['name']);
        }); 
    });
    console.log(result);
    resolve(result);
})
)
}

async function testFunc() {
    let res = await dbQuery();
    console.log(res);
}

testFunc();
```

Does someone know why the array res at the end is always empty? The commented statement console.log(row['name’] prints out the correct data...

Is it maybe better to use plain JS for SQLITE3? (Maybe using better sqlite3 or sth like that with JS instead of sqlite3 with TS?) Or is it better to use another database framework?

I googled and read like every TS Sqlite3 Doc but seems to be that TS and SQLITE3 are not so common combination though.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `resolve` immediately (synchronously), while the callback that provides you with `rows`, runs *later*, i.e. asynchronously.

Maybe you thought that `serialize` would block the JavaScript execution to continue until the query results come in, but that is not how it works: `serialize()` will return immediately. The purpose of `serialize` is not to block JavaScript execution, but to guarantee *"...that at most one statement object can execute a query at a time."* ([docs](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow#databaseserializecallback)). You would still get the results asynchronously. In your case, there is no advantage in using `serialize`, since you only perform one SQL statement.

You should call `resolve` when the callback -- given to to `.all()` -- is executed. So move it in there.

Some other remarks:

- Use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` + `.push()`
- Check the `err` argument to see if there was an error, and in that case reject the promise with that error
- Drop the `serialize` wrapper.

```
function dbQuery() {
    const db = new Database('./data.sqlite3');

    return new Promise(resolve => 
        db.all("SELECT name FROM board ORDER BY position", (err, rows) =>
            err ? reject(err)
                : resolve(rows.map(row => row['name']))
        )
    );
}
```